# SKSpriteNode takes too much time to be created from texture

Tags: sprite-kit, skspritenode, sktexture

I have a field full of sprites (30x30).

Before creating any sprite I am preloading my texture atlas with this code:

```
- (void)preloadAllAtlases
{
    BGLog();

    _tilesAtlas = [SKTextureAtlas atlasNamed:@"Tiles"];
    _tilesTextures = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    __weak typeof (shared) weakSelf = self;

    [SKTextureAtlas preloadTextureAtlases:@[_tilesAtlas]
                    withCompletionHandler:^
                    {
                        for (NSString *textureFullName in weakSelf.tilesAtlas.textureNames) {
                            NSString *textureName = [textureFullName componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"][0];
                            weakSelf.tilesTextures[textureName] = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:textureName];
                        }
                    }];

}
```

This method is called from singleton once - in appicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

When time comes I generate SKSpriteNodes from SKTextures and add compound node (node which contains all SKSpriteNodes) to SKScene. But... it takes from 1 to 1.5 seconds to display/render 192 sprites. With "Time profiler" I have found that [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:] takes waaaaay to much time.

Screenshot:
[image]

Is there any way to speed up sprite creation?

Thx.

Comment: you could create a sprite for each tile texture, and later copy these template sprites rather than creating sprites with texture

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, do you think copying will be faster? And one more q: my preload method is ok? I am keeping strong ref to each of my textures.

Comment: i don't think, I'd try and measure ;)  Preload looks fine actually. There are some private SKTexture methods you could override/swizzle to see if and when a texture does get loaded vs obtained from cache.

Comment: oh wait, you are running the preload from the appdelegate, that's way too early. You need to have a SKView instance, the preload code should be in the view controller (ie viewDidLoad). Rather than a singleton add the singleton code in a custom skview subclass where it belongs.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, I am adding an SKView in my viewDidLoad method and right there create an SKScene and present it. I have placed preload methods in init method of SKScene subclass, but... the same lag for about 1 - 1.5 secs.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, placed preload method in SKView initWithCoder: but the same lag :(

Comment: @AndrewShmig Hi! Were you able to solve your problem and if yes, what was a solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Damir179, hi... not quite. You can check source code here: https://github.com/NonAtomicGames/Sapper--Royal-Engineer